# Dart: How to require function to pass constant values as arguments

Tags: dart, constants

I have a function `fun` that requires a constant value `val` of type `MyType` (that can be constant), something like this:

```dart
/// [val] should only accept constant values
void fun(MyType val) {
  ...
}
```

So, for example, this would work:

```dart
fun(const MyType('Hello'));
```

But not this:

```dart
var randomValue = Random().nextDouble().toString();
fun(MyType(randomValue));
```

Is `fun` possible in Dart?

Comment: No, it's not possible. Could you give an example for why you want to do this? I may be able to propose an alternative.

Comment: I am trying to make an initializer function that only runs once during compile time, and so its arguments must not change after it has run, thereby needing those to be constant.

Comment: Seems like you're looking for something like `constexpr` in C++. This isn't possible in Dart, at least at the moment. Functions cannot be evaluated at compile time even if you pass it a constant. If you want to generate data a compile time, either do it manually or use generated code. I would say to not worry about it unless these function are actually very computationally heavy and are already affecting application performance. Even in that case, if it's not too too big, you could do this heavy init in an isolate while the main thread takes care of other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Christopher Moore in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71737678/dart-how-to-require-function-to-pass-constant-values-as-arguments?noredirect=1#comment126777708_71737678), this is not possible. As a result, an alternative solution is needed and it will vary depending on your particular use case.

For my specific use case, the alternative that I came up with is to use a class that uses the singleton and builder patterns.